# Java AES giving BadPaddingException

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, aes

I am trying to code a simple encryption and decryption method for my program in Java. It should encrypt and decrypt a string with another string as key.

While testing, a `BadPaddingException` occured.

My current method to encrypt:

```
public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secretKey) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] salt = new Hash().hashString(secretKey).getBytes();
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("Finished encryption");
            return new Base64().encodeToString(ciphertext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My current method to decrypt:

```
public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secretKey) {  
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] salt = new Hash().hashString(secretKey).getBytes();
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);
            
            byte[] decodedPlaintext = new Base64().decode(strToDecrypt);
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(decodedPlaintext);
            System.out.println("Finished decryption");
            return new Base64().encodeToString(plaintext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the followed exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
```

Comment: Since `encrypt` does `Base64Encode(AesEncrypt(plaintext))` shouldn't decrypt do `AesDecrypt(Base64Decode(ciphertext))` ?  (btw, your use of the name `plaintext` in `encrypt` is misleading, since that is not the plaintext).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed my code in that way, but it's still not working. Now i'm getting a `BadPaddingException` exception.

Comment: The way you're handling the IV seems a bit strange. The IV you use for decryption should be the same as the one that was used in the generation of the ciphertext. So you need to remember that IV (e.g. by prepending it to the ciphertext before base64-encoding, and then separate the two parts after base64-decoding in `decrypt`).

Comment: What @Michael said. In addition this is a good illustration of the foot-gun problem with low-level crypto APIs: your salt calculation fails to provide the security benefit that a salt is supposed to. Finally, decrypt should probably return whatever encrypt takes, so decrypt should return `new String(plaintext, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Thank you @President James K. Polk. Now it worked for my. Do you have a idea, how i could improve my salt calculaton?

Comment: Generate a random salt with `SecureRandom()` and prepend it to the message along with the IV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the kind help of Michael and President James K. Polk I could get the en- and decryption working and improved the generation of the salt. My mistake was, that I wasn't using the same `IvParameterSpec` for encryption and decryption.

My encryption method:

```
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secretKey) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(salt);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            byte[] ivBytes = ivspec.getIV();
            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("Finished encryption");
            byte[] outputBytes = concat(concat(salt, ivBytes), ciphertext);
            return new Base64().encodeToString(outputBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My decryption method:

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secretKey) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedCiphertext = new Base64().decode(strToDecrypt);
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedCiphertext, 0, 16);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedCiphertext, 16, 32);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedCiphertext, 32, decodedCiphertext.length));
            System.out.println("Finished decryption");
            return new String(plaintext, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```